# How to load the browser after logout from Applayout.vue page in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel Jetstream application that is using Applayout.vue page where the logout functionality is written. The logout is working but the page is not refreshing. I want the page to refresh and redirect back to login page. Can anyone help?

### AppLayout.vue

```
<form @submit.prevent="logout">
    <jet-dropdown-link as="button">
         Log Out
    </jet-dropdown-link>
</form>

<script>
import { Head, Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

    export default defineComponent({
methods: {
            
         logout() {
                this.$inertia.post(route('logout'));
            },
        }
})
</script>
```

### web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure on jetstream but Inertia and vue you can specify in the:

```
    this.$inertia.post(route('logout') ,
{
   preserveState: false,
});
```

[Inertia Link to preserve state](https://inertiajs.com/links#preserve-state)